# How to use generics as a replacement for a bunch of overloaded methods working with different types?

Tags: delphi, generics, delphi-xe7

I have a bunch of overloaded methods, all of them get an array of some type as a parameter and return a random value from that array:

```
function GetRandomValueFromArray(Arr: array of String): String; overload;
begin
     Result := Arr[Low(Arr) + Random(High(Arr) + 1)];
end;

function GetRandomValueFromArray(Arr: array of Integer): Integer; overload;
begin
     Result := Arr[Low(Arr) + Random(High(Arr) + 1)];
end;
```

etc.

How can I use generics to create a single method for array of any type? Something like this (does not compile in Delphi XE7):

```
function GetRandomValueFromArray(Arr: TArray<T>): <T>;
```

Appreciate any opinion as I read most of questions about generics and it's still not clear for me is it possible at all or not?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To use generic function, you have to convert it into method of class (weird limitation, in my humble opinion). Note that `class` function does not require to create an instance of `TDummy`

```
TDummy = class
  class function GetRandomValueFromArray<T>(const Arr: TArray<T>): T;
end;

class function TDummy.GetRandomValueFromArray<T>(const Arr: TArray<T>): T;
begin
  Result := Arr[Low(Arr) + Random(High(Arr) + 1)];
end;

intValue := TDummy.GetRandomValueFromArray<Integer>([1,3,5]);
```

Comment: Thank you so much for a quick, professional answer.

> class function GetRandomValueFromArray<T>(const Arr: TArray<T>): T;
Not very obvious syntax.

Comment: One of my desired features for Delphi is global generic functions, i.e. without the requirement that they be (static) methods of a class.

Comment: FWIW, `Arr[Low(Arr) + Random(Length(Arr))]` would achieve the same. And for dynarrays, `Low(Arr)` is always 0, so `Arr[Length(Arr)]` would work as well.

Comment: Technically `const arr: array of T` is the correct signature, as the question also has open array args and not dynamic arrays.