# Replacing overload by Generics in Delphi?

Tags: delphi

My question is very similar to '[How to use generics as a replacement for a bunch of overloaded methods working with different types?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48423105)'

I tried the suggested solution `GetRandomValueFromArray` and it gives no complitetime errors.
But the following does not compile :

```
Declaration / definition in existing class Tilib ..

    class function SetSingleBit<T>(const Value: T; const Bit: Byte): T;

    class function Tilib.SetSingleBit<T>(const Value: T; const Bit: Byte): T;
    begin
        Result := Value or (1 shl Bit);
    end;
```

Delphi 10.2 emits the error 'E2015 Operator ist auf diesen Operandentyp nicht anwendbar' (Operator not usable for the type of operand).
Does anyone know whats wrong with that ?

Answer (score 6):

The problem is that `T` can be any type, and only certain types support the bitwise `or` operator.

It is possible to [constrain generic types](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Constraints_in_Generics), so that the compiler knows more about their capabilities. For instance you can constrain the generic type to be a class, a sub class of a specific class, an interface, a value type, etc. But you cannot apply the constraint that you need, which would be that the type supports the bitwise `or` operator.

In short, the correct way to solve your problem is to use function overloading. Generics are not the solution to all problems.